# How to modify headers to RTK Query set by prepareHeaders when code splitting?

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

Using RTK Query [code generation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-generation) I have a generated slice of my API from an OpenAPI spec. Following on from that example I have extended the generated slice as described by using `generatedApi.enhanceEndpoints({/**/})`.

Now I want to add [`prepareHeaders`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#setting-default-headers-on-requests) to the slice which is typically set via `fetchBaseQuery`, and per the docs my use case is for adding an auth token to each request. As the `createApi` function is called within the generated file I'd like to avoid touching this to include custom logic.

I think I'm looking for something like `generatedApi.enhancePrepareHeaders({/**/})` which does not seem to exist yet.

How do I set headers for all requests when following the code splitting approach and without touching the generated file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, that is only possible by writing a custom `baseQuery` function wrapping the original `fetchBaseQuery`.
From the next version of the code generator on, it will only create `injectEndpoints` calls and leave all the `baseQuery` configuration to a non-generated file.

Comment: Great so it sounds like eventually this question won't even be relevant anymore with a new version release but sounds like a reasonable interim solution. Excellent outcome!

Comment: Does the current version allow to modify prepareHeaders through `injectEndpoints`? I was looking RTK query documentation and couldn't find any information. `enhanceEndpoints` allows to modify tags but couldn't go any further with that. Could you provide an URL or example how to achieve this without creating a second api slice for auth?

Comment: What do you modify about `prepareHeaders`? `prepareHeaders` is general logic that will be applied to everything. But since everything returned from `query` will go into `fetch`, you can also just return a `headers` property with endpoint-specific headers.